# Spyder no muestra el grafico de plots que estoy cargando

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tensorflow

estaba haciendo unas pruebas de python, queria cargar este **fichero.csv de temperaturas equivalentes entre Celsius y Farenheit** :

```
Celsius,Fahrenheit
-50,-58
-40,-40
-30,-22
-20,-4
-10,14
-9,15.8
-8,17.6
-7,19.4
-6,21.2
-5,23
-4,24.8
-3,26.6
-2,28.4
-1,30.2
0,32
1,33.8
2,35.6
3,37.4
4,39.2
5,41
6,42.8
7,44.6
8,46.4
9,48.2
10,50
20,68
30,86
40,104
50,122
60,140
```

Mi codigo es el siguiente :

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot
import logging



def main():

    print('Inicio')

    #Importando Datos
    temperature_df = pd.read_csv("temps.csv")

    #Visualizacion
    sns.scatterplot(temperature_df['Celsius'],temperature_df['Fahrenheit'])
```

El fragmento de codigo bajo el comentario `#Visualizacion` deberia de pintarme la grafica.

Al ejecutarlo la consola me muestra esto :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la grafica sale vacia :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Version de python: 3.10.6

Estoy usando conda para la gestion de entornos, no se si esto puede llegar a influir, pero tengo los paquetes de tensorflow y sus respectivas ramificaciones, como matplotlib, que creo que es la que interviene en mi problema.

El tema es que no me da ningun error ni me dice nada que me pueda servir como alerta para intentar arreglar

DEBERIA DE VERSE ALGO ASI :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Hola estimado José Angel, con solo la biblioteca matplotlib y el módulo .pyplot es suficiente al menos para graficar el par ordenado que deseas graficar.

En el .csv está el par ordenado separado por comas, es lo mismo que pasar tus datos a dataframe

```
Celsius Fahrenheit
0   -50 -58.0
1   -40 -40.0
2   -30 -22.0
3   -20 -4.0
4   -10 14.0
...
```

acá importo la biblioteca matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
tempe = pd.read_csv('C:/----/tempe.csv',encoding="utf8")
```

y con solo la instrucción

```
plt.scatter(tempe['Celsius'],tempe['Fahrenheit'])
plt.show()
```

me grafica

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sino, deberías entonces revisar la instalación de las bibliotecas de Pandas y de Math, saludos